# OData-MySQL connection in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, odata

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running MySQL. I want to access it remotely using an OData connection (Tableau public free version provides only OData interface). I am looking for the right procedure to do this.. The information I could collect from this and other forums are not clear or are not specific to MySQL on Linux(Ubuntu). I apologize in advance if this is a repeat - but I don't think so. Can anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support OData out of the box. This means that you'll have to put something in between that translates OData requests over HTTP to SQL queries, and returns the MySQL resultsets as XML or JSON.

Tableau ----OData----> Converter ----SQL----> MySQL

This conversion middleware could be built using several components. If you're proficient with Java, you could build a Java app using OLingo. In .Net you'll have tooling that introspects your database structure and generates C# code. And there are several libraries that help you achieve the same thing using Node and PHP as well.